# What will happen if the disk is Full while writing the record in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

While storing records in cassandra (half of the records stored), if my disk is full and there is no space, what will happen? If any exception will be thrown, what is that exception?

The second scenario is, what if I create a new keyspace while my disk is full? If any exception will be thrown, what is that exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the disk get full means it stops its execution. I tried many times all the time it stops its execution. So your client api throws connection refused exception.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on whether or not the keyspace you are writing to was created with durable_writes=true or false (true is the default).

If it's the former and your commitlog disk is full, then an IOException will be thrown while writing to the commitlog (but not returned as part of the response), and the request will time out.

If it's the latter and your data disks are full, you'll get a successful response. But the memtable, unable to flush to disk, will keep growing in size until the whole node runs out of RAM and terminates.

In the second scenario an exception will be thrown when attempting to write to the commitlog or when attempting to flush the new schema to disk, depending on which drive is full. In both cases the request will time out.

The coming Cassandra 1.2 (currently in beta) improves handling of such cases - read [Handling Disk Failures In Cassandra 1.2](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/handling-disk-failures-in-cassandra-1-2) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get a timeout exception.  I just ran into this while trying to load data onto a host with low disk space.